# Nginx Multiple rate limiting using incoming header $http_q

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a rate limit config as follows in the http block:

```
# Rate limit config declaration
map $http_q $r_b001 {
        b001 "1";
}

# Zone config
limit_req_zone $r_b001 zone=b001:100m rate=20r/s;

# Rate limit config declaration
map $http_q $r_c001 {
        c001 "1";
}

# Zone config
limit_req_zone $r_c001 zone=c001:100m rate=25r/s;
```

And Inside location block I have

```
location /c001{
        limit_req zone=c001 burst=1 nodelay;
        limit_req_status 429;
        other config...
}

location /b001{
        limit_req zone=b001 burst=1 nodelay;
        limit_req_status 429;
        other config...
}
```

Now when I run a load test with b001 key and c001, I'm not getting the desired rate limit control. And if I add more keys and associated config's the deviation goes even further.
Where have I gone wrong and how achieve such kind of rate limit per key per location basis.

The full config is of follows:

```
geoip2 /etc/nginx/geoip/geoLite-2Country/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb {
        $geoip2_data_country_iso_code country iso_code;
}

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/geoip_config/*.conf;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/blacklisted_config/*.conf;

##########################################################################################
# Whitelist config declaration
geo $whitelist_b001 {
        default 1;
}

# Rate limit config declaration
map $http_q $r_b001 {
        b001 "1";
    default $request_id;
}

# Zone config
limit_req_zone $r_b001 zone=b001:100m rate=25r/s;

# Rate with White limit config
map $http_q $rw_b001 {
        b001 $whitelist_b001;
        default "0";
}

##########################################################################################
# Whitelist config declaration
geo $whitelist_c001 {
        default 1;
}

# Rate limit config declaration
map $http_q $r_c001 {
        c001 "1";
    default $request_id;
}

# Zone config
limit_req_zone $r_c001 zone=c001:100m rate=15r/s;

# Rate with White limit config
map $http_q $rw_c001 {
        c001 $whitelist_c001;
        default "0";
}


# API Check, regex matches to 1 if one value corresponds to 1
map $r_b001$r_c001 $API_CHECK {
        default 0;
        ~((1)) 1;
}

#Pass through check, regex matches to 1 if one value corresponds to 1
map $rw_b001$rw_c001 $PASS_THROUGH{
        ~((1)) 1;
}

server {
    #*****************************
    # LISTEN PORT AND SERVER NAME
    #*****************************
      
    listen 443 ssl http2; 
    server_name api.com;
       
    client_body_buffer_size 16k;
    client_max_body_size 16k;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/app/access.log json_output;

    #*****************************
    # ROOT PATH
        #*****************************
    root /var/www/html;

        #*****************************
        # INDEX PAGE
        #*****************************
        location / {
                try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ =404;
        }

       #***************************************
       # Key and IP Validators
       #**************************************

       if ($API_CHECK = 0) {
            return 401 '{"status": "failure","status_code": 401 ,"custom_status_code": "XXXX","request_id": "$request_id","date_time": "$date_gmt","detail": "API key is Invalid"}';
       }

       if ($allowed_country = no) {
               return 403 '{"status": "failure","status_code": 403 ,"custom_status_code": "XXXX","request_id": "$request_id","date_time": "$date_gmt","detail": "Your request to this site is forbidden"}';
       }

       if ($blacklisted_ip = 1) {
        return 403 '{"status": "failure","status_code": 403 ,"custom_status_code": "XXXX","request_id": "$request_id","date_time": "$date_gmt","detail": "Your request to this site is forbidden"}';
       }

       if ($PASS_THROUGH = 0) {
            return 403 '{"status": "failure","status_code": 403 ,"custom_status_code": "XXXX","request_id": "$request_id","date_time": "$date_gmt","detail": "Your request to this site is forbidden"}';
       }

        #*****************************
    # Application re-route
    #*****************************
    location ^~ /api {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /proxyapi/$http_q/$1?$args last;
        }

        location ^~ /proxyapi/b001 {
                        # Limit req zone inside its own block
                        limit_req zone=b001 burst=1 nodelay;
                        limit_req_status 429;
                        alias /var/www/html/risk_app/public;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ @risk_laravel_b001;
                        index index.php;

                        # Deny .htaccess
                        location ~ /\.ht{
                                deny all;
                                return 404;
                        }

                        # FastCGI Configuration
                        location ~ \.php$ {
                                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                                include fastcgi_params;
                                fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
                                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/risk_app/public/index.php;
                                fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
                                fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
                                fastcgi_param NGINX_REQUEST_ID $request_id;
                        }
        }

        location @risk_laravel_b001 {
                    rewrite /proxyapi/b001/(.*)$ /proxyapi/b001/index.php?/$1 last;
            }

    location ^~ /proxyapi/c001 {
                        # Limit req zone inside its own block
                        limit_req zone=default_zone burst=1 nodelay;
                        limit_req_status 429;
                        alias /var/www/html/risk_app/public;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ @risk_laravel_c001;
                        index index.php;

                        # Deny .htaccess
                        location ~ /\.ht{
                                deny all;
                                return 404;
                        }

                        # FastCGI Configuration
                        location ~ \.php$ {
                                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                                include fastcgi_params;
                                fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
                                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/risk_app/public/index.php;
                                fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
                                fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
                                fastcgi_param NGINX_REQUEST_ID $request_id;
                        }
        }

        location @risk_laravel_c001 {
                    rewrite /proxyapi/c001/(.*)$ /proxyapi/c001/index.php?/$1 last;
            }

        location /ping {
        access_log off;
        return 200 '{"status":"succes","status_code": 200}';
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your requests really have a header `q`?

Comment: Yeah. It does have.

Comment: Show full request and full config

Comment: This request will not be processed by `location /b001`

Comment: Sorry, just now edited the entire code. Have a look please.

Comment: The request is of follows: `curl -H 'q:b001' 'https://example.co/api'`
The application is working as expected, everything is re-written.

Comment: Still not in `location /b001`

Comment: Exactly it is redirected to location `/proxyapi/b001`. Is that what you are seeing here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148610/discussion-between-rajesh-and-alexey-ten).